# Angular.js HTTP Get using $routeParams

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am having a problem trying to get information from a array using Angular.js + PHP.

The idea is: When the user goes to `/post/76` (for example), the script will get the ID and return all relevant information (title, content, views, etc).

$routeProvider

```
carolvaladares.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/post/:postId', {
            templateUrl : 'views/post.html',
            controller  : 'postCtrl'
        })
});
```

Controller

```
carolvaladares.controller('postCtrl', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

    var postId = $routeParams.postId;

    $http.get("php/get-posts.php?id=" + postId).then(function (response) {
        $scope.post = response.data;
    });

});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    require_once("connect.php");
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $q = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = '$id'");
    } else {
        $q = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM posts");
    }

    $result = array();

    while ($get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        $result[] = $get;
    }  

    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

(In this case, if the `id` is specified, it will only get data for one post. Otherwise, it will list data for all posts).

There is no problem until now. But when I try to print a single field of the array, it returns an empty object `[]` on console and does not show anything in the HTML.

HTML

```
<div id="post">
    {{post.title}} / DOES NOT WORK /
    {{post}} / WORKS / (PRINTS THE WHOLE ARRAY)
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

**(EDITED)**

Array

```
[
   {
      "id":"76",
      "titulo":"Carrot Cake Americano",
      "sub":"Para esse Fim de Ano, aproveite essa receita maravilhosa de bolo de cenoura!",
      "corpo":"<p>Receitinha mara pra quem vai passar o dia 24 com a barriguinha no fog&atilde;o tipo eu. <strong>o\/<\/strong> Nada mais, nada menos que ele, o tradicional <strong>Carrot Cake Americano.<\/strong><\/p>\r\n<p><strong><img src=\"http:\/\/www.carolvaladares.com.br\/staff\/uploads\/2015\/materia_gastronomia3_carrotcake_cv.jpg\" alt=\"\" \/><\/strong><\/p>\r\n<h2>Bora cozinhar!<\/h2>\r\n<p><strong>Massa &ndash; Ingredientes:<\/strong> <br \/><strong>2<\/strong> x&iacute;caras de farinha de trigo <br \/><strong>1<\/strong> x&iacute;cara de a&ccedil;&uacute;car <br \/><strong>12<\/strong> x&iacute;cara de a&ccedil;&uacute;car mascavo <br \/><strong>2<\/strong> colheres de ch&aacute; de canela em p&oacute; <br \/><strong>1<\/strong> colher de ch&aacute; de noz-moscada <br \/><strong>2<\/strong> colheres de ch&aacute; de bicarbonato de s&oacute;dio <br \/><strong>1<\/strong> colher de ch&aacute; sal <br \/><strong>1\/2<\/strong> x&iacute;cara de passas <br \/><strong>1\/2<\/strong> x&iacute;cara de ovo <br \/><strong>2<\/strong> claras de ovos <br \/><strong>2<\/strong> x&iacute;caras de cenoura ralada <br \/><strong>1\/2<\/strong> x&iacute;cara de ma&ccedil;&atilde; ralada <br \/><strong>1\/3<\/strong> de x&iacute;cara de &oacute;leo <br \/><strong>3<\/strong> colheres de sopa de &aacute;gua quente<\/p>\r\n<p><img src=\"http:\/\/www.carolvaladares.com.br\/staff\/uploads\/2015\/materia_gastronomia_carrotcake_cv.jpg\" alt=\"\" \/><\/p>\r\n<p><strong>Cobertura &ndash; Ingredientes:<\/strong> <br \/><strong>500g<\/strong> de Filadelphia <br \/><strong>1<\/strong> x&iacute;cara de ch&aacute; de a&ccedil;&uacute;car de confeiteiro <br \/><strong>1<\/strong> colher de ch&aacute; de extrato de baunilha <br \/>Nozes para decorar<\/p>\r\n<p><strong>Modo de preparo:<\/strong> <br \/>&mdash; Pr&eacute;-aque&ccedil;a o forno a 250&ordm;C <br \/>&mdash; Pulverize duas bandejas de bolo redondo (9 polegadas) com spray de cozinha sem gordura. <br \/>&mdash; Misture a farinha, os dois tipos de a&ccedil;&uacute;car, canela, noz-moscada, bicarbonato de s&oacute;dio e sal em uma tigela m&eacute;dia. <br \/>&mdash; Bata o ovo e as claras em uma tigela grande. <br \/>&mdash; Adicione a cenoura, ma&ccedil;&atilde;, &oacute;leo e passas e &aacute;gua quente, mexendo at&eacute; misturar. <br \/>&mdash; Com uma esp&aacute;tula, adicione a mistura de farinha &agrave; mistura de cenoura e mexa at&eacute; misturar. <br \/>&mdash; Espalhe a massa uniformemente nas bandejas de bolo. <br \/>&mdash; Asse os bolos at&eacute; dourar cerca de 30-32 minutos.<\/p>\r\n<p>Deixe esfriar por 15 minutos. Retire os bolos da forma e deixe esfriar completamente.<\/p>\r\n<p>Para fazer a cobertura, com a batedeira em velocidade m&eacute;dia-alta, bata os ingredientes da cobertura at&eacute; ficar homog&ecirc;neo. Recheie o bolo e cubra com o creme de cream cheese.<\/p>\r\n<p><img src=\"http:\/\/www.carolvaladares.com.br\/staff\/uploads\/2015\/materia_gastronomia2_carrotcake_cv.jpg\" alt=\"\" \/><\/p>\r\n<p>Doce tem que ser bonito, por isso eu sempre fa&ccedil;o cobertura em bolo com bico de confeiteiro, da&iacute; vai da imagina&ccedil;&atilde;o de cada um. Pique as nozes ou use-as inteiras e jogue por cima.<\/p>\r\n<p>Deixe esfriar e depois se<strong> destrua<\/strong> com o <strong>bolo deuso!<\/strong><\/p>",
      "colunista":"denise",
      "slug":"gastronomia\/carrot-cake-americano",
      "thumbnail":"staff\/uploads\/2015\/denise-materia_gastronomia3_carrotcake_cv.jpg",
      "tags":"carrot cake, cake, carrot, cenoura, bolo, receita, americano, estados unidos, eua, usa, bolo de cenoura",
      "source":"",
      "data":"2015-12-22",
      "hora":"13:00:00",
      "views":"56",
      "categoria":"gastronomia",
      "aprovado":"1"
   }
]
```

**(EDITED)**

The solution was `{{post[0].x}}` and for the HTML content `ng-bind-html` along with the dependence `ngSanitize`

Comment: If requesting one row don't need a new outer php array for it, just return that row which would then become javascript object ... otherwise try `{{post[0].title}}`

Comment: @charlietfl That worked for the title, but {{post[0].body}} is a HTML, and it's printing now as plain text...

Comment: that needs to use `ng-bind-html` ...`{{}}` is only for text. Read docs about ng-bind-html regarding use of `$SCE`

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks! Using ng-bind-html and the dependence ngSanitize it worked!

Answer (score 1):

can you show how the printed out array looks? Would help in debugging.

Anyway... My first guess would be that you are missing 1 level of the array when accessing it like

```
post[0].title
```

Because: `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an array and you put that array into an array and encode it with `json_encode`.

My second guess would be that you have to parse the response first, as its JSON: do

```
$scope.post = JSON.parse(response.data);
```

Comment: `$http` will parse the json internally

Comment: JSON.parse() returned a error. But post[0].title worked fine. Thanks!